Micro front-end using webpack and module federation. Loading remote React app in Angular shell
Micro front-end using webpack and module federation.
Problem statement.
I have two web apps,

One is an angular app which is the shell(host in this case) app.
Second is a newly created react app(remote in this case) created using the CRA(create react app).

I want to dynamically load the full remote react app exposed using the webpack configuration inside my host angular app when a certain route is hit './remote'.
 configs: 

remote (react) app:

webpack.config.js


plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "reactApp",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./App": "./src/App", // Exposing the entry point
      },
      shared: {
        react: { singleton: true },
        "react-dom": { singleton: true },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
    }),
  ],



 exposing the ./App component (don’t know if it will be exposed as a esm module of the native component)

Moving to the angular (host app) configs:

I have installed @angular-architects/module-federation and created a webpack.config.js file for custom configs.
webpack.config.js:


plugins:
[
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      library: { type: "module" },
      name: "temp",
      remotes: {
        reactApp: "reactApp@http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js",
      },
      shared: share({
        "@angular/core": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: "auto",
        },
        "@angular/common": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: "auto",
        },
        "@angular/common/http": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: "auto",
        },
        "@angular/router": {
          singleton: true,
          strictVersion: true,
          requiredVersion: "auto",
        },

        ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors(),
      }),
    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin(),
  ],



I have a app.route.ts where all my routes are defined for the module, I’m loading the remoteEntry.js using the loadRemoteModule() provided by the @angular-architects/module-federation-runtime.  here is the route path:
 


{
    path: ‘remote',
    loadChildren: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        remoteName: 'reactApp',
        remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:8080/remoteEntry.js',
        exposedModule: './App',
      }).then((m) => m.default),
  },



After trying different configuration like type: module in loadRemoteModule({}) but nothing worked. I’m getting the following error in host console:  
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵmod')
at getNgModuleDef (core.mjs:2562:29)
see screenshot for better understanding
As per my understanding I looks like angular is expecting a module from remoteEntry.js but the ‘./App’ exposed in remote app is a react component that is causing the problem.  can anyone help me in achieving this.(loading the complete react app as a module in angular host app when certain route is hit)
attatching the screenshots for better understanding:
webpack.config.js of remote react app

index.js of remote react app

bootstrap.js or remote react app

App.js of remote react app

webpack.config.js of host angular app

app.routes.ts of host angular app




but you are trying to render "React component" as a "Route" in angular. obviously angular router does not know how to render react components out of the box. I think the easiest way to integrate would be to create ReactRendererComponent and render route with this component and pass the "load remote" logic via resolve resolve: {reactPieceToRender: () => loadRemote....} 
